# Sample dask dataframe with unknown chunk sizes

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I am trying to read a large `.parquet` as a dask dataframe and sample it:

```py
ddf = dd.read_parquet("big_data.parquet")
sample_ddf = ddf.sample(frac=0.03)
```

which yields the following error:

```
ValueError: Arrays chunk sizes are unknown: (nan,)

A possible solution: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/array-chunks.html#unknown-chunks
Summary: to compute chunks sizes, use

   x.compute_chunk_sizes()  # for Dask Array `x`
   ddf.to_dask_array(lengths=True)  # for Dask DataFrame `ddf`
```

If we follow the suggested way with `ddf.to_dask_array(lengths=True)`, then we will get a dask array, not a dataframe. But I want to keep working with dataframe API.

Is there a way to compute the chunksizes and stay with the initial dask dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet looks OK, are you sure there is no array with a similar name somewhere?

Try this to see if you can reproduce the error:

```py
from dask import datasets
ddf = datasets.timeseries(npartitions=3)
sample = ddf.sample(frac=0.01)
sample.head()
#                        id     name         x         y
# timestamp                                             
# 2000-01-01 23:08:48   990  Norbert  0.706884 -0.615900
# 2000-01-01 00:27:04  1052    Sarah -0.681106  0.364827
# 2000-01-01 03:33:16   971   Yvonne  0.223484  0.993253
# 2000-01-01 22:03:13  1010  Charlie -0.256335 -0.394489
# 2000-01-01 13:11:01   986    Laura  0.394507  0.276051
```